# MSBuild error: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace error only when build with OutputDirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

I have a c# project that is referred in 2 Solutions, both the solutions have respective executable projects in .Net framework 4.6. When I try to build the solution and respective projects using MSBuild without Output Directory, both solution builds fine.

However, when I try to build the solution and respective projects using MSBuild with Output Directory, solution1 builds successfully but solution 2 fails with an error:

> (CoreCompile target) ->
>     ConfigurationProvider.cs(1,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helper' does not exist in the namespace 'Shared' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Code\Shared\Shared.Configuration\Shared.Configuration.csproj]

I have tried to explain the scenario below:

Scenario1:

> - Solution: Sol1
> - Executable project: Sol1ExecProject, in .Net framework 4.6
> - Classlibrary1(referred by Sol1ExecProject): SharedCL1, in .Net framework
>     3.5
> - Classlibrary2(referred by CL1): SharedCL2, in .Net framework 3.5

Scenario2:

> - Solution: Sol2
> - Executable project: Sol2ExecProject, in .Net framework 4.6
> - Classlibrary1(referred by Executable project): SharedCL1, in .Net framework
>     3.5
> - Classlibrary2(referred by CL1): SharedCL2, in .Net framework 3.5

The project failing is a SharedCL1 as shown above and it complains about not finding namespace in SharedCL2. This issue is happening when I execute MSBuild command to build by specifying an OutputDirectory. If don't specify output directory, it builds successfully.

Can somebody help me on what the issue is? Also, let me know if you need any other information on this.

Things I have tried:

- I changed the .Net Framework of both shared projects to 4.6 --> Same result

Answer (score 1):

What are .Net framework of both projects?
If you have different versions of project and if you try to add reference of latest version project to lower version project you might get this error?
Also please share screenshot of error you are getting.

Comment: I have added details in main question.

Comment: Are these shared projects  dll reference to your main project or project reference?

Comment: One should **not** include screenshots of error messages etc., but only post pure code in ascii!

Comment: @Harish, They are project reference.

Comment: @user69453, agree. Hence, I did not attach image and there is no code in my problem.

Comment: Agree. Code is enough. Earlier I had same error. That was due to project dependencies. I was able to resolve that issue by adding project reference instead of DLL reference.

Comment: Yes, this is not dll reference. Everything here is project reference.